# Running a particular c file in linux

Tags: c, linux

i am very new to unix/linux/c which i guess is why i am in this predicament.

Anyway, i have just completed a c programme assignmnet and am trying to run it from linux terminal. So far i can create the main programme by

navigating to the folder
running gcc myFile.c
then doing .a/.out

this then runs my programme from the terminal window. Thats fine, however to test our output out teacher gave us another file - i guess it has certain conditional checks to tets our outputs are correct. On inspection it appears to be a .exe file with the name myFile_ok.exe

to run it i have tried to do the above steps

navigating to the folder
doing ./myFile_ok.exe

but i get an error saying myFile_ok : cannot execute binary file

Any ideas how i actually can run this file at all?

Thank you

edit: there is also a make file if that makes answering my question any easier?

Comment: What does the makefile look like?

Comment: no idea how to use it to be honest - the reason being that i have done all of my coding in dev-c++ in windows, the teacher said he will be marking it in unix i guess so i just wanted to check on here if it was working, how can i check/inspect the make file to see what it looks like? - sorry about this

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `wine` or `mono` to run it, since it's not a Linux executable. Run `file` against it to be sure.

Comment: If it is a linux executable you could go "sh myFile_ok.exe"

Comment: could you provide me with an example of how to do this please, i appreciate it maybe considered spoon feeding me solutions but i have done the hard graft of getting my programming done, i just want to check it tbh ! :D

Comment: "file myFile_ok.exe" - will tell you what kind of file it s. "wine myFile_ok.exe" will potentially run the program if it is a windows executable (sometimes wine can run an exe with no problems, sometimes not)

Comment: "Run file against it" means type `file myFile_ok.exe` in the shell and examine the output.

Answer (score 1):

If the filename ends in `.exe` it is most likely a Windows executable, which you would not be able to run under Linux.  (Maybe you could run it under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) but that's probably beyond the scope of your assignment).

Probably easier to recompile your program on a Windows PC and test there.  If you get [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) you can still compile with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Put the makefile in the same directory as the c file and run `make` in the terminal. The makefile means that you shouldn't have to worry about the compilation steps - it'll just do it for you.

Comment: it just printed the following

gcc -g -Wall   -c -o myFile.o myFile.c
gcc -g -Wall -o myFile myFile.o

Comment: Is there anything else in the directory now?

Comment: a .o file that wasn't there before

Comment: That run of make almost certainly didn't make an `a.out`. It should have made `myFile.o` and `myFile` (the latter being an executable).